# laravel - @if won't accept database variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

How can I solve this? I've tried anything but I still can't compare the uuid from the database with a local id I created.

[image: error code]

Comment: I wonder why you used `{{}}` there, you didn't use it in your `@foreach`. It's just `@if ($task->uuid == $id)` https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#if-statements

Comment: thanks! it's working! But is this the right way to pass a variable from the controller to the view?

Comment: No problem. Not sure what this has to do with passing a variable from the controller to the view.

Comment: `return view("/todo", compact('clients'), compact('tasks'))->with($id);`

Comment: yeh it does not detect my variable that I'm trying to push to my view

Comment: `return view("/todo", compact('clients', 'tasks', 'id'));` should do it. `dd($id);` before that to see if `$id` is set

Comment: Hero! It works! Big thanks, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to use {{}}, as they internally render to echo().

The comparison is just:

```
@foreach($tasks as $task)
    @if($task->uuid == $id)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to use {{}} in controll statements of blade temple. {{}}  Is used while rendering any variable on the views.